# Update table using join - The multi-part identifier "Fileld" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm updating the fields using `update` query, which i gave the below code, when I'm update my query it shows the below error, & need the clear solution.

> Error : The multi-part identifier "a.NOTYETTAKEN" could not be bound.

```
--DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(NOTYETTAKEN Int, 
WORKINPROGRESS Int, 
COMPLETED Int, 
UNDERTESTING Int,
NOTPOSSIBLE Int,
STATUSNAME Nvarchar(50),
DEPARTMENTNAME Nvarchar(50),
COUNTS Int)

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT 0,0,0,0,0,StatusName,DepartmentName,COUNT(*) AS 'COUNTS' 
FROM Test..Task
GROUP BY  StatusName,DepartmentName

--DROP TABLE #Temps

CREATE TABLE #Temps
(NOTYETTAKEN Int, 
WORKINPROGRESS Int, 
COMPLETED Int, 
UNDERTESTING Int,
NOTPOSSIBLE Int,
DEPARTMENTNAME Nvarchar(50),
COUNTS Int)

INSERT INTO #Temps(DEPARTMENTNAME)
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENTNAME FROM Test..Task

SELECT * FROM #Temp
SELECT * FROM #Temps

UPDATE #Temps SET 
a.NOTYETTAKEN=b.NOTYETTAKEN,
a.WORKINPROGRESS=b.WORKINPROGRESS,
a.COMPLETED=b.COMPLETED,
a.UNDERTESTING=b.UNDERTESTING,
a.NOTPOSSIBLE=b.NOTPOSSIBLE
FROM #Temps a
INNER JOIN #Temp b 
ON a.DEPARTMENTNAME=b.DEPARTMENTNAME
```

Comment: Try using `UPDATE a` instead of `UPDATE #Temps`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, its working fine for me. but its not update any numbers in table, it shows same table which i have got earlier in #temps. no field was updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table alias specified in a `FROM` clause cannot be used as a qualifier in `SET` column_name so your update query is not valid one.

You should write like below by creating an alias in an update statement on SQL Query.

```
UPDATE a
SET    a.NOTYETTAKEN = b.NOTYETTAKEN
      ,a.WORKINPROGRESS = b.WORKINPROGRESS
      ,a.COMPLETED = b.COMPLETED
      ,a.UNDERTESTING = b.UNDERTESTING
      ,a.NOTPOSSIBLE = b.NOTPOSSIBLE
FROM   #Temps a
       INNER JOIN #Temp b
            ON  a.DEPARTMENTNAME = b.DEPARTMENTNAME
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, its working fine for me. but its not update any numbers in table, it shows same table which i have got earlier in #temps. no field was updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  UPDATE a SET 
        a.NOTYETTAKEN=b.NOTYETTAKEN,
        a.WORKINPROGRESS=b.WORKINPROGRESS,
        a.COMPLETED=b.COMPLETED,
        a.UNDERTESTING=b.UNDERTESTING,
        a.NOTPOSSIBLE=b.NOTPOSSIBLE
        FROM #Temps a
        INNER JOIN #Temp b 

ON a.DEPARTMENTNAME=b.DEPARTMENTNAME
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, its working fine for me. but its not update any numbers in table, it shows same table which i have got earlier in #temps. no field was updated.